# Implicit Function Theorem Problem - Computational Confusion

Tags: multivariable-calculus

This problem gave me a hard time on a practice test for the last ~hour. I suspect that the problem is just book-keeping, being a lot of things to write down and keep track of.

Let $f(x,y,z):\mathbb{R}^3 \to \mathbb{R}$ be a $C^1$ function such $f(0,0,0) = 0$, $\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}(0,0,0) \neq 0, \frac{\partial f}{\partial z}(0,0,0) \neq 0$ and $\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}(0,0,0) + \frac{\partial f}{\partial z}(0,0,0) \neq -1$. Show that there are $C^1$ functions $\phi$ and $\psi$ such that the following system of equations has a solution in a neighborhood of the origin.

$f(x, f(x,y,z), z) = 0$,

$f(x,y, f(x,y,z)) = 0$

It's clear from the hypotheses that $y$ and $z$ may be locally eliminated using the implicit function theorem. What I would like to do is something like the following: Write everything in terms of $x$, and define a function $F: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}^2$, where the pre-image of $0$ corresponds to the solutions of this system. If the derivative of $F$ is non-zero, I want to use the implicit function theorem on the functions I produced above to locally eliminate $y $ and $z$ to provide the solutions to this equation.

I think that the issue is just computing the derivative of these maps, because of all the repeated variables - the composition of a function with itself in several variables might just be making my head spin. Either way, can anyone help me sort this out? Is this the right way to approach this, or is there a better way?

Comment: Where do $\phi, \psi$ appear?

Comment: Sorry, I should have been explicit, they eliminate $y$ and $z$ in the system of equations, i.e. the equations are really $f(x, f(x, \phi(x), \psi(z)), \psi(z) ) = 0$ and $f(x, \phi(x), f(x, \phi(x), \psi(x)) ) = 0$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $g_1(x,y,z) = f(x,f(x,y,z),z), g_2(x,y,z) = f(x,y, f(x,y,z))$.

Note that we can view $(g_1,g_2)$ as a function $g: \mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}^2$.

Compute $\det \begin{bmatrix} {\partial g_1(0,0,0) \over \partial y} & {\partial g_1(0,0,0) \over \partial z} \\
{\partial g_2(0,0,0) \over \partial y} & {\partial g_2(0,0,0) \over \partial z} \end{bmatrix}$ and show that it is non zero using the given assumptions.

Then there are functions $\phi, \psi$ such that
$g_1(x,\phi(x), \psi(x)) = g_2(x,\phi(x), \psi(x)) = 0$ in the vicinity of $x=0$.

**Addendum**:

${\partial g_1(0,0,0) \over \partial y} = ({\partial f(0,0,0) \over \partial y})^2 = a^2$.

${\partial g_1(0,0,0) \over \partial z} = {\partial f(0,0,0) \over \partial y}{\partial f(0,0,0) \over \partial z} + {\partial f(0,0,0) \over \partial z} = ab+b$.

${\partial g_2(0,0,0) \over \partial y} = {\partial f(0,0,0) \over \partial y} + {\partial f(0,0,0) \over \partial z}{\partial f(0,0,0) \over \partial y}= a + ab$.

${\partial g_2(0,0,0) \over \partial z} = ({\partial f(0,0,0) \over \partial z})^2 = b^2$.

$\det \begin{bmatrix} a^2 & ab+b \\
a+a+b & b^2 \end{bmatrix} = -ab(a+b+1) \neq 0$.

Comment: Right, this is what I wanted to do. The issue seems to be computing the derivatives. I think the composition is screwing with my head. Thanks though. I'm glad that I'm on the right track.

Comment: I added the derivative computation.